# How to write code for 2 columns and one row in vba using for loops

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for code to loop through 2 columns and one row.
i- row, j and r - columns

Here 2 tables with 7 columns starting from 13 till 20 and 237 till 244.

Based on values in 2 table I want to select cell in first table.
I want to first select `Cells(i, j).Select` and check for value `Cells(i, r).Value` and paste or comment in `Cells(i, j)`

```
For i = 2 to Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
For j = 13 To 27
For r = 237 To 244
```

Let me know for solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question it seems that you need answer for `"How to refer adjacent cells?"`

For that you can use Offset() property in excel vba.

It works like this:
Assume you are referring to Row no. 1 (i.e. i=1) and column j. 
Now you want to refer same row but column r; you can use:

```
Range("Your_Range").Offset(0, 7).Select
```

Comment: Thanks @Avidan, I have 7 columns in each table. I want to loop through all the 7 columns of both tables for each row. I would use offset if it was only one column.

Answer (score 0):

I found the logic myself, Thanks all for looking into this.
Here is the logic:

```
r = 237
For i = 10 To Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
For j = 13 To 20
If Cells(i, r).Value = "A" Then
Cells(i, j).Select
r = r + 1
Next j
r = 237
Next i
```